# Is there a way to combine range, cells, value and offset?

Tags: excel, vba

I have done a loop and I was wondering if I do a cell reference by combining it with offset such as

```
If (range1.Cells(i, j).Offset(1,0).Value <> range2.Cells(i, j).Value) Then
```

But I run into an error. Is there anyway of going about it without defining other integers?

Comment: @bonCodigo I receive a mismatch error

Comment: As Gary "answered" already, that codeline can work. To find an error, you might want to check if all references are valid, and maybe you want to convert the values of your cells to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The line of code **can** work..............you need to see what is going on........use *OnError* to get to:

```
k = vbCrLf
    MsgBox i & k & j & k & range1.Cells(i, j).Offset(1, 0).Address & k & range1.Cells(i, j).Offset(1, 0).Value & k & range2.Cells(i, j).Address & k & range2.Cells(i, j).Value
```

to see why the code is failing.